# How to prepare tiny salted squid for cooking?

Tags: seafood, squid

So, I have a bag of tiny salted squid. I love squid, but I've never cooked them and have no idea what to do with this. They're whole, and the bag says that they've been steamed, but I don't know if that means they're ready to eat as is or if they need further cooking.

At the moment, my best guess is to look up the squid cleaning instructions in Hazan's *Classic Pasta Cookbook* or in *Time-Life Pasta* and hope they apply as well to tiny squid as they do to the larger squid pictured in those books, and then use them in some sort of pasta dish, and hope the fact that they're tiny and already steamed doesn't interfere.

So -- can I clean them in the same way as full size squid? How does the steaming affect their preparation? And what can I do with them? I realize the last question is pretty broad, so I'm mostly interested in answers to the first two, but I'm also open to suggestions for what one can use a bunch of tiny salted squid for.

[image: Bag of frozen steamed salted tiny squid]

Comment: Can't help you but for an interesting read check this out http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2159692/Womans-mouth-falls-pregnant-squid-biting-sea-creature-scientists-claim.html for why you must make sure you clean them properly :)

Comment: Were those frozen or refrigerated? Do they have an expiration date? Just curious :)

Comment: @DeirdraStrangio They are frozen; they have no expiration date.

Comment: I think she's getting at how long they've been frozen. If they've been in there much over a year they probably won't taste very good.

Comment: Hello ToxicFrog, people were confused, thinking that you are asking for recipes, which is very off topic here. So I changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

Those are meant to eat with rice, though you can it on your own. They aren't really salted, they were steamed with some salt, then frozen.

Comment: Did you have any hints on how they'd be taken from frozen to ready to eat? Would you normally just defrost and toss through some warm rice or do they taste better after being steamed for a while?

Comment: Usually steamed. To be honest, I'm never a fan of frozen cooked seafood as they can have some funky smell. These are close enough to the dim sum version that if you toss them with some scallions, ginger, and a splash of mirin (or shaoxing wine), then steam them, it would be much more palatable.